# Group By in a table of oracle objects

Tags: oracle

I'm selecting some info from a table of objects and populating another type.

I'm trying to use a GROUP BY clause in a table of objects.
However I keep getting the `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

```
my_type          object_type1;
l_TBL_OF_my_type object_type1_tbl; --table of object_type1
Source_type_TBL  object_type2_tbl; --table of another object_type

SELECT my_type(TBL.NAME,
               TBL.SOURCE_NAME,
               null,
               null,
               TBL.TARGET_NAME,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               1,
               NULL) BULK COLLECT
      INTO l_TBL_OF_my_type
      FROM TABLE(Source_type_TBL) TBL
      GROUP BY TBL.TARGET_NAME;
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? You're not doing any aggregation, as far as I can tell. It would help if you could update your question to provide a full test case so that we can recreate your types, tables, data etc ourselves (since we can't see your database or its contents), as well as the data you're expecting to be returned by your select statement.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: Is this work if you don't use my_type () Bulk COLLECT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it.

I had to group by all the selected fields.

```
SELECT my_type(TBL.NAME,
               TBL.SOURCE_NAME,
               null,
               null,
               TBL.TARGET_NAME,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               1,
               NULL) BULK COLLECT
      INTO l_TBL_OF_my_type
      FROM TABLE(Source_type_TBL) TBL
      GROUP BY TBL.NAME, TBL.SOURCE_NAME, TBL.TARGET_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
`COLLECT` is an aggregate function that takes as its argument a column of any type and creates a nested table of the input type.
`cast` - convert temporary collection into your collection.

```
SELECT cast(collect(my_type(TBL.NAME,
               TBL.SOURCE_NAME,
               null,
               null,
               TBL.TARGET_NAME,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               NULL,
               1,
               NULL))  as object_type1_tbl)
      INTO l_TBL_OF_my_type
      FROM TABLE(Source_type_TBL) TBL
      GROUP BY TBL.TARGET_NAME;
```